# Clustering short time series

Tags: time-series, clustering, classification

I would like to classify a relatively large set (over 9000) of short times series. The length of each sequence varies, but I would say about 80 % has between 2 and 9 observations. While I could use a simple trendline (maybe combined with a variance measure) to describe each these sequences, I would like to go a step beyond this solution.

What other kinds of methods could I utilize to cluster the "visual appearance" of these sequences? The ultimate goal of the classification is to gain a understanding of what type of trend/style/behavior each sequence is exhibiting.

Comment: The fact that the series differ in length greatly (greatly because they are short) will be a stumbling-block for any attempt of classification, even just visual one.

Comment: Classify as in supervised learning a map to a given target class label? Or did you mean clustering?

Comment: Did manage to use the wrong wording there: what I want to do is cluster.

Comment: Try running them through OPTICS with an appropriate dsitance function, e.g. DTW.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you few hints:

1. You could use dynamic time warping to extract similarity between your sequences. Please see : [Can someone please explain dynamic time warping for determining time series similarity?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22209/can-someone-please-explain-dynamic-time-warping-for-determining-time-series-simi)
2. Cave plot (visualization as you have stated) is another option. http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/ms/departments/sia/project/misc/caveplot.html
3. If you use R, http://www.rdatamining.com/examples/ts-mining may give you some hint
4. You may want to see a discussion on similar topic at [Time series 'clustering' in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/time-series-clustering-in-r)