# DTW - time axis streching

Tags: dynamic-time-warping

i am currently researching dynamic time warping (DTW). DTW is flexible because the time axis is streched and The sequences are "warped" non-linearly in the time dimension to determine a measure of their similarity (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping). What i dont understand is how the time axis are "streched"? i see that one point in one sequence can be mapped to multiple points in another sequence. Is this the meaning of "warped" ?

I did not find any source explaining this part good for me. Thank you

Comment: Do you find an answer in some of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22209/can-someone-please-explain-dynamic-time-warping-for-determining-time-series-simi,

Comment: no unfortunately not, I haven't found anything that answers my question more precisely